# Unable to upack ISO 8583 F137 using JPOS

Tags: iso8583, jpos

I'm trying to introduce F137 to my ISO 8583 processing. I'm using following xml configurations in packing and unpacking the ISO message for f137.

```
<isofield
id="137"
length="2"
name="Application Transaction Counter"
class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_BINARY"/>
```

I'm able to pack the F137 where I'm able to see F137 in outgoing message,

```
<send>
    <isomsg direction="outgoing">

        <header>16010201E10000000000000000000000000000000000</header>
      <field id="0" value="0210"/>
      <field id="2" value="933456______7663"/>
      <field id="4" value="000000000200"/>
      <field id="7" value="0906144357"/>
      <field id="11" value="123456"/>
      <field id="12" value="144357"/>
      <field id="13" value="0906"/>
      <field id="18" value="6012"/>
      <field id="19" value="356"/>
      <field id="22" value="0911"/>
      <field id="25" value="59"/>
      <field id="28" value=" 5       "/>
      <field id="32" value="441370"/>
      <field id="37" value="727523083909"/>
      <field id="38" value="231043"/>
      <field id="39" value="00"/>
      <field id="41" value="     101"/>
      <field id="42" value="CA-IDCode-77765"/>
      <isomsg id="43">
        <!-- org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericSubFieldPackager -->
        <field id="1" value="Acceptor 11              "/>
        <field id="2" value="NW           "/>
        <field id="3" value="IN"/>
      </isomsg>
      <isomsg id="44">
        <field id="15" value="4233"/>
      </isomsg>
      <field id="48" value="          3"/>
      <field id="49" value="356"/>
      <field id="55" value="AA55AA55" type="binary"/>
      <field id="59" value="CA123700052"/>
      <field id="60" value="9100F0000500" type="binary"/>
      <isomsg id="62">
        <!-- org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericSubFieldPackager -->
        <field id="1" value="1"/>
        <field id="2" value="153621623779500"/>
        <field id="7" value="11234123412341234123412345"/>
        <field id="20" value="0000909090"/>
      </isomsg>
      <isomsg id="63">
        <!-- org.jpos.iso.packager.Base1SubFieldPackager -->
        <field id="13" value="02F0F0"/>
        <field id="19" value="210"/>
      </isomsg>
      <field id="102" value="00023830"/>
      <field id="104" value="5700040102D7D75F00761006F0F6F5F4F3F40105F1F2F3F4F50210F6F5F4F3F2F1F0F0F0F0F3F3F4F2F3F3030997998182A4848488810404A385A2A30509A289958781979699850602E2D50709A289958781979699850802F0F10A0ED985838997898595A340D58194850C09A289958781979699850D09A28995878197969985" type="dataset" />
      <field id="119" value="35623"/>
      <!-- 123{ 68{02:10, 03:12321232123, 04:123412341}} -->
      <field id="123" value="68001C0202F1F0030BF1F2F3F2F1F2F3F2F1F2F30409F1F2F3F4F1F2F3F4F1" type="dataset" />
      **<field id="137" value="1232" type="binary"/>**
    </isomsg>
  </send>
```

but during unpacking jpos throws following exception.

```
<session-error>
    <iso-exception>
      org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLHNUM: Problem unpacking field 32 (org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Field length 96 too long. Max: 11) unpacking field=32, consumed=54
      org.jpos.iso.ISOException: org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLHNUM: Problem unpacking field 32 (org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Field length 96 too long. Max: 11) unpacking field=32, consumed=54
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOBasePackager.unpack(ISOBasePackager.java:265)
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg.unpack(ISOMsg.java:420)
    at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.unpack(BaseChannel.java:924)
    at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.receive(BaseChannel.java:692)
    at org.jpos.iso.ISOServer$Session.run(ISOServer.java:155)
    at org.jpos.util.ThreadPool$PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:72)
    </iso-exception>
```

Does JPOS support fields greater than F128. Btw Application works properly without F137.

Answer (score 1):

ISO-8583 defines 128 fields. Systems that use fields beyond 128 are quite unusual, and weird (I see this sample message seems to come from Bhutan). That said, jPOS supports them. 
I suggest you search the jPOS forum for the keyword 'tertiary bitmap':

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/jpos-users/tertiary$20bitmap%7Csort:date